# Can't generate params in state (PACT-testing problem)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, pact

I use [@pact-foundation/pact@latest](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js) (for quick deployment of my case there is a simple [jest](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/examples/jest) example)

Using this code:
[image]

I have generated this PACT file:
[image]

It is generated according to specification 3 (these are settings):
[image]

Problem:

How can I make the final PACT file contains `state params`? Like this:
[image]

[Here is an example](https://habr.com/ru/post/451132/). Here just `providerStates`. But I would like to get it through the official PACT library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible. Pact JS does not yet support the full feature set of pact spec v3. See https://docs.pact.io/feature_support for featur coverage across languages.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script that will temporarily solve this problem:

**`fix.js`**

```
const folder = "pacts" // folder with tests

const fs = require("fs")

try {
    fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach(fileName => {
        const fullPath = `${folder}/${fileName}`
        const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(fullPath).toString())

        json.interactions = json.interactions.map((el) => {
            if (Array.isArray(el.providerState)) {
                el.providerStates = el.providerState

                delete el.providerState
            }

            return el
        })

        json.metadata.pactSpecification.version = "3.0.0" // first create tests with specification 2, since matchers are not supported in version 3

        fs.writeFileSync(fullPath, JSON.stringify(json))
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

To use execute the command `$`**`node fix`**

Or add to the `package.json`, to the `scripts` object, something like this:

**`package.json`**

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test:pact": "jest --config ./pact_jest.config.js && node ./fix.js",
    "publish:pact": "node ./publish.js"
 }
...
```